# Assigning List Values to Excel Cells - Python

Tags: python, excel, selenium

Fairly new to Python so please bear with me. I've created a program using Selenium that logins into a website to extract some sales data in a html table. I've managed to navigate through the site to the relevant page and copy all the table data using the following:

```
columnInfo = []
columns = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tbl"]/tbody/tr/td')
for column in columns:
      columnInfo.append(str(column.text))
```

Which returns a long string of data back, which has everything I need:

['Location1', '', '', '55', '55', '1', '  2%', '1', '', '10', '11', '', '  0%', '66', '38', ' 0.6:1', '2', '', '11', '1100%', '   0%', ' 100%', '    66', '  3441', '   574', 'Location2', '', '', '8', '8', '', '  0%', '1', '1', '9', '11', '1', '  9%', '19', '17', ' 0.9:1', '', '1', '3', ' 400%', '  13%', '  27%', '    19', '   991', '   209', 'Location3', '', '', '13', '13', '', '  0%', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '8', ' 0.6:1', '4', '1', '1', '', '   8%', '', '    13', '   678', '   104', 'Location4', '', '', '151', '151', '', '  0%', '1', '', '23', '24', '', '  0%', '175', '105', ' 0.6:1', '', '', '4', '', '   0%', '  17%', '   175', '  9125', '   209', 'Location5', '', '', '14', '14', '', '  0%', '', '', '2', '2', '', '  0%', '16', '11', ' 0.7:1', '', '', '3', '', '   0%', ' 150%', '    16', '   834', '   156', 'Location6', '', '1', '34', '35', '', '  0%', '1', '', '3', '4', '', '  0%', '39', '11', ' 0.3:1', '', '1', '2', '', '   3%', '  50%', '    39', '  2034', '   156', 'Location7', '1', '', '10', '11', '', '  0%', '', '', '8', '8', '', '  0%', '19', '18', ' 0.9:1', '', '1', '4', '', '   9%', '  50%', '    19', '   991', '   261', 'Location8', '', '1', '6', '7', '1', ' 14%', '', '', '2', '2', '', '  0%', '9', '18', ' 2.0:1', '3', '1', '1', ' 200%', '  14%', '  50%', '     9', '   469', '   104', 'Location9', '', '', '6', '6', '', '  0%', '2', '', '2', '4', '', '  0%', '10', '10', ' 1.0:1', '', '1', '5', '', '  17%', ' 125%', '    10', '   521', '   313', 'Location10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '16', '', '  0%', '16', '35', ' 2.2:1', '', '', '2', '', '', '  13%', '    16', '   834', '   104', 'Location11', '2', '', '4', '6', '', '  0%', '1', '', '7', '8', '', '  0%', '14', '33', ' 2.4:1', '', '', '1', '', '   0%', '  13%', '    14', '   730', '    52', 'Location12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '1', '', '  0%', '1', '', ' 0.0:1', '', '', '1', '', '', ' 100%', '     1', '    52', '    52', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', 'TOTALS', '3', '2', '301', '306', '2', '  1%', '7', '1', '83', '91', '1', '  1%', '397', '304', ' 0.8:1', '9', '6', '38', '1467%', '   2%', '  42%', '   397', ' 20701', '  2294']

Is there any way of writing each value to a new cell. With a new row starting with each location (I've changed them to location1, 2 etc)?

My aim is to have this run automatically every day to update the spreadsheet, which in turn will be feeding a dashboard with up-to-date sales data.

Comment: you can write it into a csv file as row. if you know the length of columns, you can break this list as rows and write it into a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Your data has 25 columns per row. Loop in chunks of 25 and write it to file. I'll use `csv` as a simple way to write it to file for excel.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(*[iter(columnInfo)]*25):
        writer.writerow(row)
```